# statement spilling over more than one line

Tags: python, pep8

PEP8 tells me that the maximum line length should be 79. This sounds a bit like punched cards, and I'm used to longer lines, but as I learn Python, I'm trying to conform to the standard style.

Consider this line:

```
partsList[r][newPurchaseNotes] += partsList[r+1][newPurchaseNotes]
```

When indented 4 stops (using 4-space tabs per PEP8), it overflows.  (If I use PEP8 underscore separators rather than Java-style mixed case, it's worse.)

If I break it into two lines like this:

```
partsList[r][newPurchaseNotes] 
    += partsList[r+1][newPurchaseNotes]
```

...it is a syntax error (unexpected indent).  Breaking it like this:

```
partsList[r][newPurchaseNotes] += 
    partsList[r+1][newPurchaseNotes]
```

...it is ALSO a syntax error (invalid syntax).

Here are two obvious solutions, neither of which I like:

- use shorter names for variables
- break the one statement into two with intermediate variables:

  ```
  s = partsList[r+1][newPurchaseNotes]
  partsList[r][newPurchaseNotes] += s
  ```

In researching this forum, I did find suggestions for reducing indentation levels for loops and for conditionals.  In my case, I had if nested in if nested in a while inside a function.  I changed the logic to reduce one level of if statements, but it was not enough to keep the line in 79 characters.

Comment: The reason you didn't get code formatted text originally, was because the indentation you gave it indicated it was a continuation of the above bullet point. It needed to be indented _even more_

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed that the problem was gone (more indentation added, the comment about why it was not formatted was removed) when I went in to edit it.  How did that happen?  Can others besides me edit the text?

Comment: Yes, anyone with enough rep can edit it, but the edits will be reviewed and potentially rolled back if they aren't actual improvements

Comment: Thanks again.  Obviously I am a stackoverflow newbie as well as a Python newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't use semi-colons to denote the end of lines. Use a backslash to indicate the line is continued on the next line:

```
partsList[r][newPurchaseNotes] \
    += partsList[r+1][newPurchaseNotes]
```

The other way you can break a statement over multiple lines in python, is if the break happens within parentheses or brackets. In your example here, you *could* break the line between `[` and `]`, but that would be really ugly.

One possibility is:

```
partsList[r][newPurchaseNotes] = (
    partsList[r][newPurchaseNotes] +
    partsList[r+1][newPurchaseNotes]
)
```

I'm not sure that that's an improvement though.

Comment: I know Python does not use ; for end of statement like C.  The backslash is a reasonable solution, but it's not elegant.  Surely there's something better?

Comment: I mentioned the semi-colons by way of explaining _why_ you use backslash to break a line: Other languages require you to delimit _every_ line. The _other way_ to have valid line breaks in python, is within parenthesis or brackets. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  The second suggestion seems better to me.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, while PEP-8 calls for 79-character lines, a more-accepted rule of thumb is 100 characters.

That said, this particular line seems relatively verbose and repeats a fair amount of logic between the two statements. What's the goal? It's quite possible that given a bit more context, this particular line can be simplified substantially.

**EDIT: Code sample:**

So, the goal is to essentially merge line items that share certain attributes. This seems like a great way to use an object:

```
class LineDeduper(object):

    def __init__(self, indices, addition_points):
        self.items = {}
        self.indices = indices
        self.addition_points = addition_points

    def add(self, item):
        mergekey = tuple(item[x] for x in self.indices)
        if mergekey in self.items:
            self.merge(mergekey, item)
        else:
            self.items[mergekey] = item

    def merge(self, key, item):
        for idx, val in enumerate(item):
            if idx in self.addition_points:
                self.items[key][idx] += val

    def to_list(self):
        return [x for x in self.items.values()]
```

Just initialize with lists of the relevant deduplication indices, as well a list of the indices that need to be added together, and add each line from the CSV. Once done, you can easily get out the results.

Comment: I am consolidating two records of information by summing the quantity (not shown here) and by concatenating two items of purchase history into one string.  My data came from a CSV file read into a 2d list.

I don't see redundancy, nor do I see a way to simplify it, aside from using an intermediate variable, which seems ugly to me.

Comment: Is the goal to sum the quantity of _all_ items in the table, or just these two items in particular?

Comment: I am consolidating two or more records that have the same content for two specific fields of information (not the two discussed here).

Comment: @MarkColan - see the above code sample. I think it should do what you need, and it does it in a Pythonic way.

Comment: Great!  The example is well beyond my newbie ability to understand it, but it looks like the next place to go for me to learn.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!